# error while configuring bind

Tags: networking, server, dns

I get this error when i try to verify the dns configs:

> /etc/bind/named.conf.options:27: unknown option 'sudo'

these are my configs:

`$ sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf`

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server na$
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information$
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you cus$
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.c$

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

`$ sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if 
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "ataxiagames.com" {
        type master;
        file "etc/bind/for.ataxiagame.com";
        allow-transfer {192.168.109.132; };

};
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/rev.ataxiagames.com";
        allow-transfer {192.168.109.132; };
};
```

Comment: Please add the contents of the `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` file - since according to the error message that seems to be where the error lies

Comment: According to the error message, your `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` has at least 27 lines and there is an error (likely involving an erroneously placed `sudo`) on line 27